# How can I query a polymorphic association by id and attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently build a Rails 5.2 app.

In this app I have three objects, Project, Customfield and CustomfieldAnswer.

**Project:**

```
- id
- title
```

**Customfield**

```
- id
- title
```

**CustomfieldAnswer**

```
- id
- answerable_id
- answerable_type
- customfield_id
- answer
```

A Project has_many CustomfieldAnswers.
A CustomfieldAnswer is connected with a polymorphic association (answerable).

I tried this query (has_answer) and it returns all CustomfieldAnswers that matches but how can I use that method (or another) in a query for Projects that got these:

```
class CustomfieldAnswer < ApplicationRecord
  include Defaultable

  belongs_to :customfield
  belongs_to :answerable, polymorphic: true

  def self.has_answer(customfield_id, answer)
    CustomfieldAnswer.where(customfield_id: customfield_id, answerable_type: 'Project', answer: answer)
  end
end
```

I want to query all Projects that has a specific CustomfieldAnswer (by it's Id) with a specific answer (by string). How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: `project.customfield_answers.where(customfield_id: customfield_id)` should work if you have defined `has_many :customfield_answers` association in the Project model.

Comment: It needs to be a query and not on a single object

Comment: Where are you defining `answerable`? The `has_many` needs to be in a concern called Answerable, no?